# how to call function/api with UITextField.text after 3rd character

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am new to swift and want to implement search feature, I want to call api after my search textField's characters exceeds-3char.
means user type 1 more character api will call.i tried code below but didn’t work.
i shall be very thank full.if some one help me.

```
  func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
   if textField == self.mySearchField{
            if string.count >= 4{
               print("more than 4 ")
               
            }
            else
            {
            return true
            }
          }else{
          return true
    }
```

function should recall after every time user add more character.

Comment: add a target for UIControl.Event `.editingChanged` and check `textField.text.count >= 4`

Comment: @LeoDabus   thanks brother it worked great ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
       if textField == self.mySearchField{
          let count = self.mySearchField.text.count + string.count
             if count >= 4{
                   print("more than 4 ")   
             }else {
                return true
             }
          }else{
              return true
        }
```